# Core Data Migration crash at addPersistentStoreWithType

Tags: ios, core-data-migration

My App Crashes when I tried to implement migration.

```
if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error])
```

even though NSZombie is enabled and  i get the exec_bad_access in the tread stack

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (  _managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = nil;


        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }

//    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ToGoNow" ofType:@"momd"];
//    NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"ToGoNow" withExtension:@"momd"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    if ([modelURL checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:&error] == NO){
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);     //[[NSAlert alertWithError:err] runModal];
    }


    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"ToGoNow.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

    if ([storeURL checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:&error] == NO){
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);     //[[NSAlert alertWithError:err] runModal];
    }

    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];


    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

#pragma mark - Application's Documents directory

- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

To Troubleshoot the issue, I tried the following 
  1. delete the versioned model

1. import an old copy of the model (without versioning) run the app (runs fine in simulator)
2. add a new model version
3. add a new attribute of type int16 to an existing entity
4. update the corresponding NSManagedObject class to that entity with a new nsinteger property
5. rerun the app, and it still crashes at:

   if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error])

I've also turned core data debugging and here is what I got after crash:

```
2014-01-11 18:34:28.233 ***[17494:70b] CoreData: annotation: Connecting to sqlite database file at "/Users/***/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/7822B8E6-36B6-4EE5-8A42-253EEA4F3093/Documents/ToGoNow.sqlite"
2014-01-11 18:34:28.235 ***[17494:70b] CoreData: sql: SELECT Z_VERSION, Z_UUID, Z_PLIST FROM Z_METADATA
2014-01-11 18:34:28.237 ***[17494:70b] CoreData: annotation: Disconnecting from sqlite database.
2014-01-11 18:34:28.240 ***[17494:70b] CoreData: annotation: Connecting to sqlite database file at "/Users/***/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/7822B8E6-36B6-4EE5-8A42-253EEA4F3093/Documents/***.sqlite"
2014-01-11 18:34:28.241 ***[17494:70b] CoreData: sql: pragma journal_mode=wal
2014-01-11 18:34:28.242 ***[17494:70b] CoreData: sql: pragma cache_size=200
2014-01-11 18:34:28.243 ***[17494:70b] CoreData: sql: SELECT Z_VERSION, Z_UUID, Z_PLIST FROM Z_METADATA
```

`